# excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js shows values in filter list from the above tables

Tags: javascript, excel, jsp, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to creare a Excel like Filter in my bootstrap table using excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js. The filter works but it shows not only the values from the working table but also the values from above tables.
That's my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Scheda Cliente</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-style.css">
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js"></script>

<meta name=”vs_targetSchema” content=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5″&gt;>
<style>
th, td {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="Forniture_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
        <h3 class="sub-header">TABLE 1</h3>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="dt-buttons btn-group">      
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <table id="tableA" 
        class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" 
        data-filter-control="true" 
        data-show-multi-sort="true">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                    <th>1a</th>
                                    <th>1b</th>
                                    <th>1c</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                        <c:forEach items="${fornitureList}" var="forniture">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${forniture.nrContratto}</td>
                                <td>${forniture.commodity}</td>
                                <td>${forniture.statoContratto}</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    
                </table>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="FattureP_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
        <h4 class="sub-header">TABLE 2</h4>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        </div>      
        <table id="tableB" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                <th>2a</th>
                <th>2b</th>
                <th>2c</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <c:forEach items="${listfattureClientePagate}" var="fattureClienteP">
                <tr>
                    <td>${fattureClienteP.nrContratto}</td>
                    <td>${fattureClienteP.nrFattura}</td>
                    <td>${fattureClienteP.dataFattura}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </table>
        </div>
    
    <script>     
        
        $(function () {
              $('#tableA').excelTableFilter();
        });
        
        $(function () {
              $('#tableB').excelTableFilter();
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the immage below filter in table 2 column b shows the last value from table 1 column b.
thanks
[image]

Comment: i tried your code with cdn you have provided for `excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js` ..it was giving same behaviour .Then i have search and i found [this](https://github.com/chestercharles/excel-bootstrap-table-filter/blob/master/dist/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js) page ..when i  use this `js` it was working .Can you test it and see once ?

Comment: Thanks@Swati I fix the reference in the function call but how can i add the new js reference?. I changed the reference to <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chestercharles/excel-bootstrap-table-filter/master/dist/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js"></script> but it do not load the javascript because the filter has disappeared. thanks

Comment: no copy that js code and save in some file at your computer with name `excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js` and access same under your `<script src="pathtofile"></script>`

Comment: Hi, I've saved the file into the WebContent/js folder (same level as WEB - INF) and changed the page reference to <script src="js/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js"></script>. But the file is not loaded. I checked it in the browser dev tool-> Network and the file has a status of 302. I added the path "/js/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js" into the mapConfig but it still doesn't load the code. thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442630/10606400) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107788/how-include-an-external-js-file-in-a-jsp-page/42076844#42076844) answer might help you.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the page reference to : <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js"></script>. file is in WebContent/js folder. but it still not working. In the network tab the http status for that file is 302. If I click on it, the browser doesn't open the file on a new tab as it does with the other but I get redirected to the home page. Im my applicazione all the request with the "/ "are redirect the home page. So I changed that servlet and it Works. Thanks so much!!! And now the filter work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
$('table').excelTableFilter({
```

to

```
$('#divTable').excelTableFilter({
```

Setup a id and name for the div as divTable!